# How to insert a map into a popover - bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, leaflet

I need to have a popover which can present a map inside its body. I did this basic example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Popover Example</h3>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover">Toggle popover</a>
  </div>

  <script>
    let script = `
    <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);

    L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
    <\/script>`;

    console.log(script);
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        title: 'A nice map inside a popover!',
        content: "<div id='map' style='background: gray;'></div>" + script,
        html: true
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It sends html content which contains a div and script for the leaflet map. It doesn't work.
I am not sure this approach would work out and maybe you know a better way to have a map once a table cell or any other element is clicked.

Comment: Not sure why you're writing a "literal" script tag and placing it in a variable, then appending it to an element. Additionally you reference `src="script/script.js"`, which in this context, who knows what's in that file. What is `leaflet.js` and what is `popper.js`? Please, in the future, elaborate and explain as much as you can. It's better to list an extensive amount of information than too little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot append script tags directly on the content prop of the popover method. To make this, you will need listen to some event triggered after the popover is rendered, like `shown.bs.popover`:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', () => {});
```

Inside, you'll be able to call Leaflet and create the map instance. I attach a CodePen with the concept (I applied some CSS to make adjustments on the popover layout to show the map correctly) https://codepen.io/geekzolanos-dev/pen/gOpwRrR

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. That is what I need and the explation is also important because I am still learning and this helps a lot in this process

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code snippet:

```js
      $(document).ready(function() {
           $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
             title: 'A nice map inside a popover!',
             content: "<div id='map' style='background: gray;'></div>",
             html: true
           });
           
           $("[data-toggle=popover]").on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
         
         var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
         
         L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
         attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);
         
         L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
         .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
         .openPopup();
         });
         
         });
```

```css
 #map{
         height:300px;
         width:300px;
         }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
  
      <div class="container">
         <h3>Popover Example</h3>
         <a href="#" data-toggle="popover">Toggle popover</a>
      </div>
```

Hope this will helps you.